# What non-poisonous chemicals can get rid of SLS effectively?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, surfactants

Whenever I brush teeth, there are some kind of bubbles sticking inside the cavity and that's uncomfortable, it should be SLS as found on the internet. Does anyone know how do I get rid of those bubbles things easily?
Eat/Drink sth? Tell me if anything is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Addition: SLS represents sodium lauryl sulfate, chemical exist in our cleaning product: toothpaste, shampoo,   etc. I don't know what it is for but seems it produce bubbles as long as the product is used.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Find out how to beautify your posts in the [help center}(/help) and take the [tour] to learn more about this site. Enjoy!

Comment: It would definitely help most readers if you explained what SLS is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SLS is [highly soluble in water](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium_dodecyl_sulfate#section=Chemical-and-Physical-Properties) (100g/L)

Therefore, in the specific case of your teeth having lots of bubbles around them after brushing, you should simply [gargle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargling) your mouth with water to remove the excess SLS.